# Renaming a table in pandas hdfstore

Tags: python, pandas, pytables

I am using pandas to join several huge csv files using HDFStore. I'm merging all the other tables to a base table, `base`. Right now I create a new table in the HDFStore for the output of each merge, which I call `temp`. Then I delete the old base table. Finally, I copy `temp` to `base` and start the process over again on the next table I need to join.

This would be much more efficient if I could simply rename `temp` to `base`. Is this possible?

Comment: Luke, I'm curious why you wouldn't just append additional csv's directly to the base table, rather than have the intermediate (slow) step of creating a new table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You have to delve into the [methods from PyTables](http://pytables.org/svn/pytables/tags/std-0.7/doc/html/usersguide5.html), on which `HDFStore` depends.

```
Out[20]: 
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: test.h5
/a            frame        (shape->[3,1])

In [21]: store.get_node('a')._f_rename('b')

In [22]: store
Out[22]: 
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: test.h5
/b            frame        (shape->[3,1])
```

The same method works on `frame_table` appendable nodes.

Comment: Thanks, oddly there doesn't appear to be any speed improvement.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not deeply familiar with the internals. If @Jeff drops by he might be able to shed some light on this.

Comment: using your procedure the file will continue to grow; you should ptrepack if you are deleting a lot. not clear where you think a speed up would be

Comment: I think the speedup would be renaming the node `temp` to `base` instead of copying the node `temp` into `base`, naively analogous to `mv` vs `cp`.

Comment: @Jeff, Dan Allan is right about where I thought the speed-up might be.  Would ptrepack be faster than deleting and changing the name or is that essentially what ptrepack is doing?

Comment: No renaming is fine and @Dan Allan answer is right. Deleting doesn't reclaim space, nor make the store more efficient. ptrepack repacks the file to compute an optimal chunksize and reclaims space. See here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#compression

Comment: I found this method helpful for other things too (such as getting a list of children in a store group). List of properties/methods: http://pytables.github.io/usersguide/libref/hierarchy_classes.html